# Formatting date parameter in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I want to format a date parameter in my report. The date looks like this in my database and my report "yyyy-mm-dd" (2014-04-17 for example). I tried to do it with that line of Code which I always saw on other posts:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format($P{Startdatum})
```

That doesn't work of course and I am getting this error:

> Error filling print... Error evaluating expression : 
>       Source text : new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format($P{Startdatum})
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
>       Source text : new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format($P{Startdatum})
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:203)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:591)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:559)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.evaluateExpression(JRFillElement.java:966)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluateText(JRFillTextField.java:456)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluate(JRFillTextField.java:440)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:259)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:455)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillBandNoOverflow(JRVerticalFiller.java:457)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillPageHeader(JRVerticalFiller.java:421)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:282)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:151)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:822)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:61)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:276)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745)
>       at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:891)
>       at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
>       at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
>       at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:301)     at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)     at Berichtsheft_1397742638211_397211.evaluate(Berichtsheft_1397742638211_397211:223)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:190)
>       ... 20 more  Print not filled. Try to use an EmptyDataSource...

I am using this parameter for one of my Queries ! Could that be the reason for the error ? Or is the syntax simply false ? Or is there even any other reason for this error ?

Comment: @Alex K why retag the tag ireport ?

Comment: This question is not about using *iReport* designer. It is relates to *JasperReports* engine

Comment: Uhm, Okay I thought using the iReport for editing my expressions is enough of a reason to use it as a tag.. Seemingly not

Comment: Do you think the result will be different in case using *Jaspersoft Studio* or simple text editor?

Comment: You got a point right there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use just parameter name like this:-

```
  new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format($F{Startdatum})
```

and check the report "Language" in property panel you should change it to "java".

To change the report language go to Windows --> Report Inspector- and click on the report name and then --> Windows--> Properties.

Here in down the panel you can select the Language.

Comment: Can you also post the JRXML code? Are you able to get the parameter value in the report without using any code just parameter only?

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: Sharad I have a question, what is the difference between F{fieldname} and {fieldname} and why your solution worked? This seems a litle bit dark side of the jasperreport :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use that expression instead

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse($P{Startdatum})
```

Comment: Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-11-10"